# Chebyshev's inequality for 1 standard deviation results in 0?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

In applying Chebyshev's inequality to a probability distribution, the following is the given equation:

$$p(\mu - c*\sigma \le X \le \mu + c*\sigma) \ge 1 - \frac{1}{c^2}$$

This indicates for any value of "c" as a weight to the standard deviations, we have a probability that is greater or equal to $1 - \frac{1}{c^2}$. This means that for $c=2$, we have $1 - \frac{1}{2^2} = 0.75$, and for $c=2$, we have $0.89$. However, this also means that for $c=1$, we end up with $0$.

While this technically makes sense that the probability of values being within 1 standard deviation is greater than 0, unless I am mistaken, doesn't this just offer nothing analytically? The value of 0 basically just states that the probability of X exists, no?

Furthermore, for values less than 1 the logic breaks down as the probability becomes negative, so the use of $\ge$ cannot be correctly applied here. So I'm curious if the value of $c$ in this equation is limited to discrete integers, or if there is something that I am missing?

Comment: That's because Chebyshev is a very weak result, it applies to all distributions, so it is the strongest thing you can say about one standard devition for *all* distributions.  What's amazing about Chebyshev is that you can say anything at all about *all* distributions, for more than one standard deviation.

Comment: I strongly disagree in calling the inequality a weak result.  It is one of the most astonishing result in statistics I've ever met.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe It is the strongest completely general result, but it is much weaker than other possibilities when you know something about the distribution. The corresponding inequality for normal variables for example is much tighter.

Answer (score 2):

Chebyshev's Inequality is true for any $c > 0$, but you are right that it only provides useful information for $c > 1$.

This is actually surprisingly easy prove. Define $\mu = E(X)$ and $\sigma^2 = E((X-\mu)^2)$. Observe that for any $c \geq 0$ we have $\mathbb{1}\left\{\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right|\geq c\right\} \leq \frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2 c^2}$ where $\mathbb{1}\{\cdot\}$ is an indicator function equal to 1 if the event inside the brackets occurs and 0 otherwise. (To see this, suppose $\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right| \geq c$. Then the left-hand side equals 1 but the right-hand side is $\geq$ 1. If $\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right| < c$, the left-hand side is 0 but the right-hand side is positive.)

Since the expectation operator is monotonic, we can take expectations of both sides to obtain
$$
\Pr\left(\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right|\geq c\right) \leq \frac{E(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2 c^2} = \frac{1}{c^2}
$$
Since $\Pr\left(\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right|\geq c\right) = 1- \Pr\left(\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right|\leq c\right)= 1 -\Pr(\mu- \sigma c \leq X \leq \mu + \sigma c)$, we can rearrange to obtain the desired inequality.

The proof illustrates how you could derive many other inequalities of this type. Any function $g$ that satisfies

$$\left|\frac{X-\mu}{c\sigma}\right|\geq 1 \Rightarrow g\left(\left|\frac{X-\mu}{c\sigma}\right|\right) \geq 1$$

will work. For example, you could use an identical proof to show
$$
\Pr\left(\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right|\geq c\right) \leq \frac{E\left(|X-\mu|^k\right)}{\sigma^k c^k}
$$
for *all* $k > 0$.